# Adding Banks to Stripe Connect Accounts in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm dynamically creating Stripe (Custom) Connect accounts. After they are created, I want to create bank accounts and add them to the Connected user.

Here's my front-end:

```
var form = document.getElementById('bank-add');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
            country: 'US',
            currency: 'usd',
            routing_number: document.getElementById('routing-number').value,
            account_number: document.getElementById('account-number').value,
            account_holder_name: document.getElementById('name').value,
            account_holder_type: 'individual',
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                //var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                //errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server.
                $('.token').text(result.token);
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
    });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('bank-add');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
```

And here is the back-end:

```
public void OnPostAddRoutingNumber()
        {
            var token = Request.Form["stripeToken"];

            var service = new ExternalAccountService();
            var options = new ExternalAccountCreateOptions
            {
                ExternalAccountTokenId = token
            };
            var bankAccount = service.Create(
              "acct_1EFPhvA7tmSzdlaC", 
              options
            );

            var o = new AccountUpdateOptions()
            {
                ExternalAccountId = bankAccount.Id
            };
            var s = new AccountService();
            s.Update("acct_1EFPhvA7tmSzdlaC", o);
        }
```

So, I am having some confusion. The front end code is telling Stripe to create a token for this data, and then I need to create the Bank Account - using this token - in the backend, right??? Then add it to the account? But when updating the Connect Account, it says 'No such token'.

Comment: What you want to do is use the `token` to [create a source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create?lang=dotnet) and then [attach that source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach?lang=dotnet) to the customer.

Can you verify that you are passing the actual `token` string to the backend?

Comment: Yes, it gets to the backend (a new one with each test)